# How can I have two user inputs in a MySQL python execution where WHERE condition is 1 user input and the updated VALUES are another?

Tags: python, mysql, windows, pycharm

I am trying to update a table on MySQL with user input on Python. I previously set the data successfully with .format and also previously successfully selected one row from MySQL with user input where order.ID=%s (orderNo) but now I can't find a way to do them both together without getting a SQL syntax error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIP1A.png

So how do I Update my customer table and set the specified values that are user Inputted where the orders.ID = orderNo (another user input)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some text inside the `{}`, like

`"value1 is {value1} and value2 is {value2}".format(value1=variable1, value2=variable2)`

[in code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Q59.png)

You can also use `f` before the string quote, like

`f"value1 is {variable1} and value2 is {variable2}"`

[in code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVk8M.png)

Unfortunately, this way just works in >= python3.7